# Android Rotate Surface created using MediaCodec

Tags: android, rotation, android-mediacodec

I am using Camera2 APIs to capture video from the Camera. I understand that we need to rotate the preview as Camera2 does not have an equivalent of setDisplayOrientation(). Able to rotate preview using a Matrix.

I am also using the MediaCodec APIs to encode the video. The encoded video however is inverted when I rotate the phone 180 degrees. I am out of ideas on how to rotate the encoded video.

I tried KEY_ROTATION in MediaFormat while configuring. But I guess this is only while decoding (Output surface).

Thank you!!

Comment: `"Able to rotate preview using a Matrix."` who is able? if you are able, whats the problem then?

Comment: The problem is with the surface that was added using the MediaCodec createinputsurface is not rotated

Comment: so why you are not `"able to rotate preview using a Matrix."`?

Comment: There are two surfaces...one for preview (TextureView) which I'm able to rotate using a transformation matrix. The second one is from the MediaCodec, which I don't know how to rotate.

Comment: so post some of your code

Comment: probably answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40599604/192373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camera2 doesn't directly matter here - you can use MediaRecorder if you want with camera2, via [MediaRecorder.getSurface()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getSurface()) and the [MediaRecoder.setOrientationHint()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint(int)) method to set the desired orientation.

If you're using MediaCodec instead of MediaRecorder, then there's no orientation flag there; the corresponding method is [MediaMuxer.setOrientationHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html#setOrientationHint(int)), since all MediaRecoder does is write the requested orientation into the video file metadata; the actual frames are not generally rotated by the encoder.

If you're not wrapping the encoded buffers into a video file, but instead consuming them in some other way (network transmission for video chat, etc), you need to pass the orientation along with the encoded frames and apply the transform in the receiving end yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was kind of expecting this - to send orientation info with the encoded buffers.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way of actually rotating the video? This only changes the metadata which might or not be supported on certain video players

Comment: Both options are static I mean before start/prepare. Can we change this option on fly .. for video call applications to send the information to remote party about the orientation change

Comment: No, these controls only affect the container metadata (which is why they're on MediaMuxer which writes the file, not on MediaCodec that does the compression).  If you have a video call, you'll need to pass the orientation yourself alongside the compressed stream.

Comment: unfortunately my client phone doesn't have capability to transform at remote end .. so I must rotate locally and sent it to remote client. In order to avoid troubles of buffer conversion from Camera2 to encoder on devices I migrated to Surface.. but now it seems to be I've to go back to buffer method and rotate using Open GL and pass it to encoder. I really like to stick to Surface approach but I was forced to go to byte buffer method

Comment: You can still use a SurfaceTexture for Camera->GL, and then a Surface from GL->encoder.  You can pass in MediaCodec's Surface into eglCreateWindowSurface to create a render target for GL, and not have to worry about any ByteBuffer-based transport.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. Similar approach we have adopted. Now struck at realizing media codec needs to reconfigured on Camera rotation of 90 deg. Initially configured for 320x240.. now we have to configure and start for 240x320. I see bit rate can be changed dynamically but unable to find option to change resolution on fly. Since real time video call, stopping and starting codec might effect performance ???

Comment: You might be able to set up two codecs, one 320x240 and the other 240x320, and swap which you render into from GLES dynamically, but I don't know if that would run into hardware constraints on some devices.

Comment: This will be best bet. Top also showing memory occupied by H/W codec is less. 

5529 mediacodec   20   0  85M  10M 7.8M S  7.3   0.1   1:29.66 media.codec hw/+

Or

will restarting media codec on camera orientation change adds any delays?

Comment: Restarting will cause some kind of small delay, but it may be short enough to be no big issue - if someone's rotating their device, whoever is on the other end probably won't care about a slight pause as everything is already spinning about. But I don't know the numbers.

Comment: I've managed the scenario without changing frame size but did some image processing (applied black color). If decoder supports Adaptive playback, I wonder why not encoders. I've successfully tested decoder adaptive support (OMX.Exynos on Note 10)